# ¿Como verifico que una checkbox se pueda marcar solo una casilla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, options

Quiero que al utilizar una checkbox en javascript, no permita al usuario marcar más de una casilla, necesito tener:

1. CASILLA 1500
2. CASILLA 2000

y que seleccione solo una casilla.

Este es mi codigo HTML:

```html
<form id="formularioOpciones" style="display: none">
    <p>Seleccione el factor para multiplicar la superficie corporal:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="factor1500" name="factor" value="1500" />
    <label for="factor1500">1500</label><br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="factor2000" name="factor" value="2000" />
    <label for="factor2000">2000</label><br />

    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="enviarFactor" />
</form>
```

Esperaba que funcione de forma predeterminada, pero la checkbox permite marcar mas de una casilla.

Comment: Intenta con **radiobutton**.

Comment: Lee sobre la diferencia entre radios y checkbox. Como ya te dijeron, ahí son radios, no checks

Comment: Hola Manu, ¿existe una razón por la que tengan que ser si o si checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza radio buttons, estos solo permiten seleccionar un elemento:

```
<input type="radio" id="factor1500" name="factor" value="1500" />
<label for="factor1500">1500</label><br />

<input type="radio" id="factor2000" name="factor" value="2000" />
<label for="factor2000">2000</label><br />

<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="enviarFactor" />
```